# Changing variable after keypress?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a fun little game.

You have to press all the keys on the screen as fast as you can, without getting it wrong.

But struggling to change the variable after the first keypress. This is what I have:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;
    var uyhgg=13;
    function checkKeycode(e) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event) {
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        } else if (e) {
            keycode = e.which;
        }            
        if (keycode == uyhgg){
            document.write(keycode);
        } else {
            alert("you hit the wrong key");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now after `document.write(keycode);` I want it to change the variable `uyhgg` (key code) to something else. 13 is enter.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `uyhgg`?

Answer (score 3):

A call to `document.write()` after your page loads will obliterate the page.  Instead of that, I suggest you make the code update some page element.

```
if (keycode == uyhgg){
  document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = keycode;
}
```

Put a `<div>` or `<span>` or whatever somewhere on the page with that "id" value:

```
<div id='something'>your keycode will go here</div>
```

As for changing the variable, well, you should be able to just change it.

```
uyhgg = 32;
```

or whatever you need to change it according to, well, whatever the game needs.

Comment: instead of uyhgg = 32; i was putting var uyhgg=32;

Comment: Ah, yes, if you do that you'll be declaring a new **local** variable of that function, which would "hide" the global one.

Answer (score 1):

Uhmm ... you simply assign it?

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;
var uyhgg=13;

function checkKeycode(e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;

    if (keycode == uyhgg){
        document.write(keycode);
        uyhgg = 27;
        alertUyhgg();
    }
    else {
        alert("you hit the wrong key"); 
    }
}

function alertUyhgg() {
     alert(uyhgg); 
}
```